# Sort viewCount with the highest number using YouTube API?

Tags: php, sorting, youtube

I'm attempting to display multiple videos from YouTube and I'm pulling there information using the YouTube API.

I have everything working except, I'd like to sort the viewing of the videos of viewCount with the highest number being first.

I could simply convert this to a database system, but then I'd have to run a cron job (not an issue, just trying to avoid the extra need of running more code than needed.)

```
    $video = array(
        "id1",
        "id2",
        "id3",
    );

    foreach ($video as $key) {
        $api = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/$key?v=2&alt=json";

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        $yt = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
        curl_close($ch);

        $title       = $yt->{'entry'}->{'title'}->{'$t'};
        $viewCount   = $yt->{'entry'}->{'yt$statistics'}->{'viewCount'};
        $length      = $yt->{'entry'}->{'media$group'}->{'yt$duration'}->{'seconds'};
        $numDislikes = $yt->{'entry'}->{'yt$rating'}->{'numDislikes'};
        $numLikes    = $yt->{'entry'}->{'yt$rating'}->{'numLikes'};
        $average     = $yt->{'entry'}->{'gd$rating'}->{'average'};
        $minutes     = sprintf("%0.2f", $length / 60);
        $seconds     = str_replace(".", ":", $minutes);

//What I've tried, doesn't work. With and without if statement and max (Shouldn't need both, but I need the if statement to display one format of the number is higher) but too avail it hasn't successfully worked.

        $views = 0;
        foreach ($viewCount as $maxViews) {
            $views = max($views,$maxViews);
            if ($maxViews > $views) {
                echo $views;
            } else {
                echo $viewCount;
            }
        }
     }
```

This should be simple and obviously completely looking over it, thinking it's because the array values are not numbers, the numbers are being pulled from each foreach loop from the $viewCount variable.

Hoping someone can assist me and getting this fixed correctly.

Notes: I've coded this myself, but since it's a YouTube API you're allowed to use the code for yourself. JSON parsing can sometimes be a pain. Especially with YouTube's API.

Regards

Comment: Why not simply get all the video ordered with viewCount parameter : &orderby=viewCount. See : https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#orderbysp

Comment: I've taken a look at this, doesn't work for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I also find that the `order=viewCount` (as recommended here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) appears to return inaccurate results, currently a search for "ncaa" with `order=viewCount` (which you can try here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it) returns a list of videos with the first ten viewcounts in this order: 6535, 12493, 110049, 999499, 94162, 110510, 7578, 2311, 102718, 9345

Comment: Can we get Youtube videos sorted by Number of Likes i.e(FavoriteCount).